Showing $\sec6^\circ+\tan36^\circ=\cot30^\circ=\sqrt3$ without a calculator
I solved a geometry problem to the following equation
$$\cot(\theta)=\sec6^\circ+ \tan36^\circ$$,it’s answer is $\theta=30^\circ$,how can I prove that
$$\sec6^\circ+\tan36^\circ=\cot30^\circ=\sqrt3$$ without using a calculator.

Bravo and Thank you very much. I spent almost three days trying to figure out how to solve it. I even thought about using tan 60- tan 36 but fell short to reach the final result.

Hint:
$$\tan60^\circ-\tan36^\circ=\cdots=\dfrac{\sin(60-36)^\circ}{\cos60^\circ\cos36^\circ}$$
$$\text{ Again, }2\sin24^\circ\cos6^\circ=\sin(24+6)^\circ+\sin(24-6)^\circ =\sin30^\circ+\cos36^\circ-\dfrac12=? $$ using
Proving trigonometric equation $\cos(36^\circ) - \cos(72^\circ) = 1/2$
